# Magento 1.9 Tax Excluded price is displaying for Not Logged in customers

Tags: magento, tax

I have created a new tax class and configured the settings.

Tax is getting applied properly for Logged in customers.

For Guest customers, Price is showing excluded of tax.

Any help please....

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

this may be because your tax rule is applied on billing or shipping address.
Thanks

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer